# GCM - Chrome: Registration Failed - Permission Denied

Tags: javascript, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to implement Push Notifications on Chrome, and so subscribing a user to PushMessaging. However, when subscribing I get the error `Registration Failed - Permission Denied`. And I have no idea why, I have looked every single corner of the internet.

I'm using the code from this tutorial [Push Notifications on the Open Web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web?hl=en) , and the error rises when calling the `subscribe()` method.

When checking Chrome console for network changes or XHR requests nothing happens, and the error is thrown just after loading the `manifest.json` file. Also, permission is never asked to the user (and I set it manually to granted). So the error must come from somewhere else and locally. I'm leaving my manifest JSON here:

```
{
    "name": "My Super App Name",
    "short_name": "M-S-A-N",
    "icons":[{
        "src": "img/logo.png",
        "sizes": "512x512",
        "type": "image/png"
    }],
    "start_url": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "gcm_sender_id": "000000000000",
    "gcm_user_visible_only": true
}
```

Thanks a lot to anyone that may have an answer

Comment: You don't seem to have GCM permission in your manifest.json. See here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client#set_up_chrome_app_or_extension

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?